# How to register a new SharePoint App using PowerShell (instead of appregnew.aspx)?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I'm uploading my SharePoin Provider Hosted App and installing everything via PowerShell, but the only thing that I cannot find is if it's possible to register a new app using a PowerShell command instead of opening the "/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx" page.

Comment: did you check this http://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/register-and-install-app-through-powershell/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Register-SPAppPrincipal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219642(v=office.15).aspx) command to register an App using PowerShell.

Something like this:

```
$realm = Get-SPAuthenticationRealm -ServiceContext $web.Site;
$appIdentifier = $clientID  + '@' + $realm;
Register-SPAppPrincipal -DisplayName $appName -NameIdentifier $appIdentifier -Site $web
```

Look [here](http://manasbhardwaj.net/powershell-alternative-sharepoint-2013-appregnew-aspx/) for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the app in office 365 tenancy[SharePoint Online] using the below Azure AD MSOLService PS Script.

```
$clientID="7c6cbd92-073b-4bc9-9d4a-fc27749f340b";
$newClientSecret = "p/zEuKBqkZRQsz6yRpOafj2f6zZdnQYvONatGWj0N0M=";
$appDomain="Yourdomain.azurewebsites.net";
$appUrl="https://Yourdomain.azurewebsites.net/";
$appName="Your App Name"
$servicePrincipalName = @("$clientID/$appDomain")
$dtStart = [System.DateTime]::Now
$dtEnd = $dtStart.AddYears(10)

Connect-MsolService 
New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames $servicePrincipalName -AppPrincipalId $clientID -DisplayName $appName -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret -Addresses (New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address $appUrl) -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $newClientSecret -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
```

I have written an article on this. Please refer this [link](http://blog.hubfly.com/sharepoint/how-to-registerunregister-sharepoint-add-ins-using-powershell).